# jQuery-ui widget factory, event handlers and that

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I've been developing a few jQuery widgets recently but 2 things have been bothering me and so I'm coming to you hoping you'll have a nicer way to do it.

1) I quite like the fact of using "that" instead of this. Makes the code much clearer and avoid quite a lot of bugs. To make it simple I always use "that" as this of the widget.
However I don't know how to make my "that" global so what I do is:

```
$.widget("widgetName", {
    method1: function() {
        var that = this;
    },
    method2: function() {
        var that = this;
    }
});
```

As you can see that's heavy in code and not much better. I was wondering if i was valid to do:

```
 var that = $.widget("widgetName", {
     method1: function() {
         //do something
     },
     method2: function() {
         //do something
         that.method1();
     }
  });
```

Or will that pose any problem? If that is impossible how do you think is the best way to do it?

2) This is really linked to my first question and an answer to it should be enough:
For my event handlers I often need to use my "that" to call methods for eg. So what I currently do is

```
 $.widget("widgetName", {
     _handlers: {},
     _create: function() {
         var that = this;
         that._handlers: {
             handler1: function(e) { 
                 //do something
                 that.method();
             } //...
         };
         that.on("event", that._handlers.handler1);
     },
     method: function() {}
 });
```

Do you see a nicer way I could do this? My big need is to be able to move the whole initialization of that._handlers out of that._create

These are quite open questions. I'm really trying to find a way to make my jquery widget really clear and maintainable and I'm curious to know how people do.

Thanks a lot for your opinion on this.

Comment: I would simply not use `that` unless it was absolutely necessary.

Comment: Why not? `that` means for me the actual widget. The real equivalent to `this` in other languages and also I find that being systematic on something as error causing as the `this` in js especially important

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on my comment, here's how you could bind your handlers to preserve `this`

```
 $.widget("widgetName", {
     _handlers: {},
     _create: function() {
         this._handlers.handler1 = $.proxy(function(e) { 
                 //do something
                 this.method();
         }, this);
         this.element.on("event", this._handlers.handler1);
     },
     method: function() {}
 });
```

Or you could swap that around allowing for easily overriding the handlers for 3rd party developers:

```
 $.widget("widgetName", {
     _handlers: {
         handler1: function(e) { 
             //do something
             this.method();
         }
     },
     _create: function() {
         this.element.on("event", $.proxy(this._handlers.handler1,this));
     },
     method: function() {}
 });
```

**Edit:** And if you really want a global `that` variable, here's one way to do it without polluting the global scope:

```
(function($){
     var that;
     $.widget("widgetName", {
         _handlers: {
             handler1: function(e) { 
                 //do something
                 that.method();
             }
         },
         _create: function() {
             that = this;
             this.element.on("event", this._handlers.handler1);
         },
         method: function() {}
     });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: but then I have to get into e.target to get the element that fired the event. This why using `that` would be nicer.
Moreover that means everytime I bind an event I have to write `$.proxy(this._handlers..., this)` no?

Comment: Correct. Just depends on what path you want to take as the author of the plugin.

Comment: But then I still need a way to declare a global that to make it perfect. Would you by any chance have a way to do that and answer my first question. Which would by the same time answer my second question?

Comment: This is perfect thank you very much. You've now made my code much nicer and cleaner. 
Any other recommendations?

Comment: @charly Not really, I personally would still be using `.bind` until it is announced that it will be removed in a newer version, allowing your plugin to work in older versions of jQuery. As it stands now, `.bind` is not depreciated, it just isn't preferred.

Comment: Ho thanks. I've changed all my `bind`s to `on` but your opinion is right

Comment: After using what you described in the edit for a while I realized it had a major inconvenient: you can't more than one widget of a type on each page. Indeed the "that" variable references the last declared widget and therefore breaks everything I use $.proxy instead.

Comment: Sorry, i thought that was a given, it being global-ish and all.